# How to place ImageButton over ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

[image]

I'd like to do this in my RelativeLayout with two ImageButtons and an ImageView. Is it possible to do this without using marginTop? Any responses are welcomed.
My xml code:

```
        <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/imageview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
       android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
       android:background="@drawable/image2"/>

      <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
       android:background="@drawable/image3"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RelativeLayouts are almost always the right layout, they are very powerful. In your case, you can simply use 'android:layout_centerVertical="true"', but get rid of the 'layout_alignParentBottom'

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image2"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my personal experience: when in doubt, use RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `FrameLayout` in this case. In a `FrameLayout`, the z-index is defined by the order in which the items are added. So your last element inside `FrameLayout` should be `ImageButton` so that it will be drawn on top of `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should you Framelayout, and add the imageView first, after it then add the imageButton second.

Please follow this links:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-frame-layouts--mobile-4877

http://javatechig.com/android/android-framelayout-example

with Relativelayout you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your answer correctly then you can do that in code. 
After all views are assigned (`findViewById(...)` calls) add the below line to your code:

```
mMyImageButton.bringToFront();
```

Hope it helps!